# what is the best practice for forgot password process?

Tags: security, passwords, forgot-password

I am currently developing a c# web application that allows users to login with a password. A feature that I need to include is a forgot password function.

What is the recommended process for forgot password?

I was considering this:

- User clicks forgot password, enter email address
- Email sent
- Click on link in email (link only valid once and within time period)
- Taken to the site and asked to enter new password (should they also give answer to security question?)
- Password changed, email sent to user of such
- User now can log in with new password

Answer (score 3):

Your idea looks solid, but I would add some other considerations:

- Be sure that the token you are generating in the email using is using a the .Net Framework crypto classes designed for randomization, not something that seems random but is not designed for that purpose.
- Take no action on the account from the sending of the reset email (otherwise people will be able to lock other people's accounts if they know their email)
- Add a rate limiter on how many resets per hour can be generated for a given email. Otherwise somebody could DOS a user by: (a) using x bad passwords to lock the account and then (b) generating reset emails for them faster than the email system can deliver.
- Where possible defer to other systems such as OpenID. It's easy to get things wrong when you roll your own.

Comment: These are good points, only the point about locking the account after x failed logins is questionable. I would never lock an account because of bad logins, only delay the next possible login to thwart brute forcing. Also spamming the user with reset-emails should be no problem, it's as easy to spam him with normal emails from an anonymous email account.

Answer (score 0):

We have two ways to retrieve the forgot password:
1. Through registered email id 
2. Through registered mobile number

**Registered Email id:**

a. Ask the user to provide the registered email id

b. The system checks the provided email id is available in the DB or not

c. If Email ID is there in the DB then system send the Email to reset the password but if Email id is not there in the DB then system show the alert messaged.

d. The user must provide strong password while resetting the forgot password.

e. Password reset successfully and is also change in the DB with respect to the Email ID.

**Registered Mobile number:**

The process is almost same as the email but in this case, OTP will be sent over the registered mobile number.
We need to integrate the 3rd part SDK for this or we can use the imessage in IOS.